# How do I add JS and CSS to the HTML code created in the body field?

Tags: javascript, theming, wysiwyg

I am using CKEditor; there is an option to add HTML using Full HTML filter format. My HTML code is working fine, but how shall I add JS and CSS in the HTML code?

Comment: you define id or class in your html code after that use define id or class in predefined css or js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and most important: Probably you shouldn't. Both can break your site, so having them in database, where they are hard to find, is bad idea. Better would be to use classes to "trigger" predefined behaviors or styles. If you still want to do it per node, then you have two options:

1. In Full HTML, you can use inline CSS and JS all right. If you can't, go to the format settings and make sure these are not stripped.
2. [Code per Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/cpn) gives you superior editing capabilities and is more manageable. And you can just disable it if you happen to know there is malicious code, but you can't find node it's on.

   [image: CPN offcial image]

Comment: I thought I have seen this asked already, but couldn't find any earlier appearance of this question.

Answer (score 0):

go to `/sites/all/themes/yourthemename/style.css` and add the css there.

For adding JavaScript there are various ways to do it. [Read This Article](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722)

Comment: Won't help if he needs style per node. Also, if he uses ready-made theme, this change will be erased with next update.

Comment: @Molot aight u got me there, +1.

Comment: It's not a bad answer, really, and I would prefer that way - but there should be a warning about overwriting, and note about class per node.